# How to solve for singular solution of a second order linear ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

## y''-xy-y=0

My attempt

I have tried first solving this equation by putting $y=ce^{ax}$and found that $y=ce^{x√(x²+1)}$. I don't know if this is right way to solve it. Then I tried to find tangent to family of curves to find singular solution but can't solve it.Further can't think anymore so I thought approach the problem by clairaunt's equation and try to find a function of y' and then derivative it  and pluck in x+f'(p)=0 (p is first derivative of y) to find singular solution and also d²y/dx²=0 (I think this point I'm wrong) regardless it can't form function of y' I also read about p-discriminant method but it gone top of my head.
Please help me out I am new in this field.

Comment: There must be at least one typo in your equation and/or your solution.

Comment: You mean $y''-xy'-y=0$ ?

Comment: @Aryadeva Nope it's not what you suggest ed although I even think that this could be right. Answer given was y=x²/4. Give it a try maybe question is wrong and please let me know.

Comment: @Professor Vector   Can you please give me a base concept to how to solve these type of questions.

Comment: $x^2/4$ is not a solution of your DE

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-xy-y=0$$
$$y''-(x+1)y=0$$
$$y''-zy=0$$
Where $z=x+1$. This is just [Airy's differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) . The solution provided $y=\dfrac {x^2}{4}$ does not solve the DE you posted.

Comment: This DE has no singular solution ...@One-Eye-Triangle  And $x^2/4$ is not a solution of the DE.

Comment: How you checked that DE has no singular solution could you please  show me. I want to learn to approach this type of quetion so it would be a great help

Comment: A singular solution is a solution and the function provided is not a solution of the DE you posted. @One-Eye-Triangle

Comment: Ok I understand. Do you think what I have done is correct? Substitution of $$y=ce^{ax}$$

Comment: The DE is not simple to solve you can try series solution method. This DE has Airy's function as solution. I think the DE is not correct. @One-Eye-Triangle